# Office Unable to open hyperlink because of no application associated

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365, html, microsoft-word-2016

I have a problem with word unable to open an hyperlink. The error message I get is "Unable to open https://link...index.php?some_other_information. No application is associated to this file."

Microsoft Word Unable to open hyperlink:
[image]

I am able to open other web link. it is really specific to this one. Sometimes it work but it opens the web site https://link...index.php? (without the information after the '?' that open a specific page on the web site).

I have a full access on this site. When I copy and paste the site on my navigator it works correctly.

Also, I tested it with different navigator : chrome, Microsoft Edge and firefox with no luck.

Comment: Your special navigator can open your special link but no other browser as well as MS Word can open it. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Update the version of Office as it worked on a beta test version of Office. I have updated the Office version and it works. The hyperlink was complete.